# How to flatten (opposed to rounding) button corners

Tags: android, android-layout

I know how make the four edges of a button rounded using a drawable shape, but can one make the corners flat, such that the button will look like it has 8 edges (like an ocotogon)?

Comment: You can't draw octogon with shape drawable, but you can draw nine patch, vector or background in custom button by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Yuor_button.setBackgroundDrawable(//something);
```

This "something" can be an image of  octagon or you can try using [Android Shape Drawables Tutorial](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-shape-drawables-tutorial-17fbece6fef5)